# R bookdown, fontawesome5, render fails but file knits just fine in RStudio

Tags: r, latex, pandoc, bookdown

Experiencing an odd issue... using MacTeX 2018, current versions of all packages, R and RStudio ditto... I can knit a file containing fontawesome5 icons just fine in RStudio, however, render() is failing and I need to use render in a makefile to automate a build process... render() appears to set in motion a call to latexmk that appears to call tlmgr on fonts that already exist which then halts with a file not found error... any suggestions would be most welcome, hair successfully pulled out over this... thanks in advance!

Below is a minimal file needed to replicate (debug.Rmd in what follows):

```
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: no
    latex_engine: lualatex
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{fontawesome5}
---

-   \faIcon{phone}
```

If you remove `\faIcon{phone}` it renders fine and of course also builds fine in RStudio.

Here is the error message (session info follows)

```
 Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("debug.Rmd",bookdown::pdf_document2(toc = FALSE))'


processing file: debug.Rmd
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: debug.knit.md

/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS debug.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output debug.tex --template /Users/jracine/Library/R/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --number-sections --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --variable 'compact-title:yes' --variable tables=yes --standalone
tlmgr search --file --global '/fa5free0solid[.](tfm|afm|mf|otf)'
Trying to automatically install missing LaTeX packages...
tlmgr install fontawesome5
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirror.colo-serv.net/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr install: package already present: fontawesome5
tlmgr path add
tlmgr search --file --global '/fa5free0solid[.](tfm|afm|mf|otf)'

Output created: debug.pdf
Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(output_file) :
  file 'debug.pdf' does not exist
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Session Info:

```
Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value
 version  R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
 system   x86_64, darwin17.5.0
 ui       X11
 language (EN)
 collate  en_CA.UTF-8
 tz       America/Toronto
 date     2018-06-24

Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source
 backports   1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 base64enc   0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 bookdown    0.7.13  2018-06-18 Github (rstudio/bookdown@dda5f5a)
 digest      0.6.15  2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 evaluate    0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 glue        1.2.0   2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 graphics  * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local
 grDevices * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local
 highr       0.7     2018-06-09 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 htmltools   0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 jsonlite    1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 knitr       1.20.6  2018-06-22 Github (yihui/knitr@2b3e617)
 magrittr    1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 markdown    0.8     2017-04-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 methods   * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local
 mime        0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 Rcpp        0.12.17 2018-05-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 rmarkdown   1.10.2  2018-06-22 Github (rstudio/rmarkdown@1f5b299)
 rprojroot   1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 stats     * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local
 stringi     1.2.3   2018-06-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 stringr     1.3.1   2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 tinytex     0.5     2018-04-16 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 tools       3.5.0   2018-04-23 local
 utils     * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local
 xfun        0.2.5   2018-06-22 Github (yihui/xfun@b75336c)
 yaml        2.1.19  2018-05-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.2.1’
> system('pdflatex --version')
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
Copyright 2018 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.00
```

Comment: The problems are occurring in Pandoc/LaTeX, not (directly) in R, which makes it a pain to debug. Maybe try just knitting to Markdown and calling Pandoc explicitly? It looks like it may be a path/library issue, but I'm fuzzy on how LaTeX actually handles those.

Comment: Thanks for this. It turns out that pandoc is not recognizing the latex_engine command in the YAML header. Adding it explicitly in the render/pdf_document call appears to resolve the issue. Bug or feature?

Comment: Huh, curious. The YAML gets passed through the template functions (here `bookdown::pdf_document2` and `rmarkdown::pdf_document`) to `render`, which knits and calls pandoc. So it may be either an rmarkdown or pandoc issue; it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

Your Makefile is wrong. When you call

```
Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("debug.Rmd",bookdown::pdf_document2(toc = FALSE))'
```

you essentially overrode the settings in your YAML metadata (such as `latex_engine`) with `bookdown::pdf_document2(toc = FALSE)`, which has the default `latex_engine = 'pdflatex'`. That is why your intermediate .tex output was compiled with `pdflatex` instead of `lualatex`.

Either call

```
Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("debug.Rmd")'
```

if `bookdown::pdf_document2` is the only output format you need, or call

```
Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("debug.Rmd", "bookdown::pdf_document2")'
```

if you have multiple output formats set in YAML.

For the second argument of `rmarkdown::render()` (e.g., the output format), you should rarely need the form of an output format function that returns an output format (e.g., `bookdown::pdf_document2(...)`). In most cases, I believe the default (`NULL`, meaning the first format you set in YAML), or a character string (the name of the format you set in YAML) should be what you want.

Comment: Greetings Yihui - thanks for your kind comments and time... your incredible contributions to the community are appreciated!